# How to create a struct from an array of struct type?

Tags: apache-spark-sql

How can I merge all structs in an array and produce a merged struct?

For example, with Spark SQL, I am able to read the source json file and produce a column of array type, with each element in the array contains one key:value pair. For example, let's say we have the value
of an ArrayType column with col name `col`, and value:`[{a: 1}, {b: 2}, {c: 3}]`

I need to transform this array type column to a struct type, with value `{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}`.

Since I obtained the schema by reading from JSON file, I can obtain the result using the derived ordinal, like:

```
df.select(
  $"col.a".getItem(1) as "a", 
  $"col.b".getItem(2) as "b", 
  $"col.c".getItem(3) as "c")
```

The problem with this solution is that if the elements in the array is ordered differently, I will get wrong result. Is there a clean way to kind of merge all key/value structs and produce one struct cleanly? In my case there is no duplicates for the keys so I don't worry about losing data when a key/value is overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, it can be done using a combination of `explode` and `pivot`:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

val df = Seq(
  (1, Array(("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("c", 3))),
  (2, Array(("b", 5), ("c", 6), ("a", 4)))
).toDF("id", "col")

df.show(10, false)

val explodedDF = df.withColumn("col2", explode(df.col("col"))).select("id", "col2")

explodedDF.show(10, false)

val flattenedDF = explodedDF.withColumn("k", $"col2._1").withColumn("v", $"col2._2").select("id", "k", "v")

flattenedDF.show(10, false)

val pivotedDF = flattenedDF.groupBy("id").pivot("k").agg(first(col("v")))

pivotedDF.show(10, false)

import scala.util.parsing.json.JSONObject

pivotedDF.select("a", "b", "c").collect().map{row => JSONObject(row.getValuesMap(row.schema.fieldNames))}.map(println)

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

+---+------------------------+
|id |col                     |
+---+------------------------+
|1  |[[a, 1], [b, 2], [c, 3]]|
|2  |[[b, 5], [c, 6], [a, 4]]|
+---+------------------------+

+---+------+
|id |col2  |
+---+------+
|1  |[a, 1]|
|1  |[b, 2]|
|1  |[c, 3]|
|2  |[b, 5]|
|2  |[c, 6]|
|2  |[a, 4]|
+---+------+

+---+---+---+
|id |k  |v  |
+---+---+---+
|1  |a  |1  |
|1  |b  |2  |
|1  |c  |3  |
|2  |b  |5  |
|2  |c  |6  |
|2  |a  |4  |
+---+---+---+

+---+---+---+---+
|id |a  |b  |c  |
+---+---+---+---+
|1  |1  |2  |3  |
|2  |4  |5  |6  |
+---+---+---+---+

{"a" : 1, "b" : 2, "c" : 3}
{"a" : 4, "b" : 5, "c" : 6}
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, col: array<struct<_1:string,_2:int>>]
explodedDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, col2: struct<_1: string, _2: int>]
flattenedDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, k: string ... 1 more field]
pivotedDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, a: int ... 2 more fields]
import scala.util.parsing.json.JSONObject
res24: Array[Unit] = Array((), ())

scala>
```